# Html helper in asp.net-mvc, accessing sub-fields of expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I would like to write an Html helper for the following situation: I have a class Foo for which I would like to generate the following html:

```
<tr>
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foo.Name)</td>
  <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Foo.Value)</td>
  <td>@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.Foo.Unit)</td>
</tr>
```

By doing:

```
@Html.MyCustomHelperFor(m => m.Foo)
```

I have the standard type of helper, but I can't figure out the syntax to further specify the expression. I would need model binding to work on all the generated fields. Something like:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyCustomHelperFor<TModel, TValue> (
            this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(
                   "<tr>" +
                       "<td>" + helper.HiddenFor(expression.Name).ToString() + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + helper.TextBoxFor(expression.Value).ToString() + "</td>" +
                       "<td>" + helper.EnumDropDownListFor(expression.Unit).ToString() + "</td>" +
                    "</tr>");
        }
```

Comment: Just create an `EditorTemplate`. Creating an extension method for this is way overkill.

Comment: `EditorTemplates` with `@model YourModel` is much better. The custom HTML helper like that seems going wrong, you need to capture property name using `data = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, helper.ViewData)` & `data.PropertyName`.

Comment: EditorTemplates are exactly what I needed, thanks. How do I give credit to a comment?